# JavaScript error: "is not a constructor"

Tags: javascript, jquery, debugging, backbone.js, underscore.js

I'm using backbone.js along with jquery and underscore.js

Here's some of my code (it doesn't do anything yet). The strange thing is that upon hitting the url "/#users" there isn't an error. The only time the error happens is when I then click to go to a different hash and then click back to go to "/#users". Here's part of my code, with the line that receives the error toward the end `Users = new Users();` the error says "Users is not a constructor":

```
var User = Backbone.Model.extend({
    url: function(){return 'api/user/id/' + this.id;}
});

var Users = Backbone.Collection.extend({
    model: User,
    url: function(){return 'api/users';},
    initialize: function() {
    }
});

var UsersView = Backbone.View.extend({
    initialize: function() {
        this.users = this.options.users;
        this.render();
    },

    render: function() {
        _(this.users).each(function(){
        //  $('#app').append('here');
        });

        var template = _.template($('#usersTemplate').text());

        $(this.el).html(template({users: this.users}));
        $('#app').html(this.el);
    }
});

var UserView = Backbone.View.extend({
    initialize: function() {
        this.user = this.options.user;
        this.render();
    },

    render: function() {

        var template = _.template("hello {{user.name}}");

        $(this.el).html(template({user: this.user.toJSON()}));
        $('#app').html(this.el);
    }
});

var Controller = Backbone.Controller.extend({
    routes: {
        'dashboard' : 'dashboard',
        'users' : 'showusers'
    },

    showuser: function(id) {
        UserList.fetch({
            success: function(){
                new UserView({user: User});
            },
            error: function(){
                alert('an error of sorts');
            }
        });
    },

    showusers: function() {
        Users = new Users();
        Users.fetch({
            success: function(Users) {
                new UsersView({users: Users});
            },
            error: function() {
            }
        });
    },

    dashboard: function() {
        Users = new Users;
        Users.fetch({
            success: function() {
                new UsersView({users: Users});
            },
            error: function() {
            }
        });
    }
});

$(document).ready(function(){
    var ApplicationController = new Controller;
    Backbone.history.start();
});
```

the accompanying html if you're curious:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>Administration Panel</title>

    <!-- Framework -->
    <script src="/javascripts/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="/javascripts/underscore.min.js"></script>
    <script src="/javascripts/backbone.js"></script>

    <!-- Application -->
    <script src="/javascripts/application.js"></script>

    <script id="usersTemplate" type="text/x-underscore-template">
        asdf
    </script>

</head>
<body>

<div>
<a href="#dashboard">Dashboard</a>
<a href="#users">Users</a>
<a href="#products">Products</a>
<a href="#orders">Orders</a>
<a href="#pages">Pages</a>
<a href="#settings">Settings</a>
</div>

<div id="app"></div>

</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 25, accepted):

`new` can only be used with a Function as the operand.

```
new {}  // Error: ({}) is not a constructor
```

Check the type of `Users` in context: it is *not* a Function when that exception is raised.

Happy coding

---

`alert(typeof(Users))` ought to do the trick. The result should be "function" to be usable as a constructor. Take note of what it is in the failing case, and see below for a reason.

One problematic scenario (for `Users = new Users`) may be: an object is constructed from the Function `Users` and then the object (now not a Function/constructor) is assigned back to `Users` so the next `new Users` will go **kaboom!** (Look in both `showusers` and `dashboard` -- is that behavior *really* intended?)

The 'correct' code is likely: `var users = new Users; users.blahblah(...)`; that is, use a new local variable and *do not overwrite* the global Users variable/property.

---

The reason the error is only generated when "going back" to "#foobar" (a [Fragment Identifier](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fragment_identifier)) is that no new page is actually loaded and thus the JavaScript is not reloaded and the current (now corrupt `Users`) is being used. **kaboom!**

Excerpt from [Fragment Identifier](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fragment_identifier):

> > If the targeted element is located in the current document, a user agent may simply focus the targeted element without having to reload it ...

Comment: I ran into this error when naming a model "history" only in FF while working in Chrome, possibly due to another library I was loading.

Comment: @steve76 Yes, any name clashes can result in icky behavior. In the case of `history` I suspect it clashing with [`window.history`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/DOM/window.history). In Firefox setting a "built-in" window property does not report an error but also does not change the value: and `window.history` is not a function/constructor.

Comment: One caveat, you can't use labda functions as constructors: `new (() => {}) // (intermediate value) is not a constructor`

Answer (score 0):

I think its Syntax Error

this happened with me when I tried to `return anonymous object` in my function

```
 var FalsEextension=false;
 ........
 ........
 return new  { FalsEextension, LargeFile };// wrong Syntax
```

and the correct Syntax is

```
 return { FalsEextension, LargeFile };
```

and you can use it like this

```
ObjectName.FalsEextension
```

Comment: Your example is already covered by the accepted answer. it fails for the same reason `new {}` fails.