# Instantiate view on backbone Router?

Tags: backbone.js, backbone-views

Can anyone help me understand this error? TIA

> TypeError: AppView is not a constructor [Break On This Error]  var
>   apView = new AppView();

```
define([
    'jquery',
   'backbone',
   'collections/Directory',
   'views/app',
   'common'
   ]   , function( $, Backbone, DirectoryCollection,AppView , Common ) {

var Workspace = Backbone.Router.extend({
    routes:{            
        "filter/:type": "urlFilter"
    },      

urlFilter: function (type) {            
        var apView = new AppView();
        apView.filterType = type;
        apView.trigger("change:filterType");          
    },

});
return Workspace;

});
```

Comment: This may provide direction - [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5655367/javascript-error-is-not-a-constructor)

Answer (score 0):

Is AppView either in scope or attached to the window object, as well as extending Backbone.View?

Comment: what do you mean attached? appView is in "app.js' file

Comment: Actually that likely isn't your problem... Try new AppView instead of new AppView().  If that doesn't work can you post your code for AppView?